# How can I return an error message if the type of args[i] is not of the expected type in Java? Is there a 'type test' function?

Tags: java, error-handling, string-parsing, arrays

So this is a class that is meant to take in as input in the CMD prompt a string and integer, i.e. "Hello" 4, and then repeat the string 4 times. Thats not a problem, and works, however I want to return an error message (i.e. "Invalid argument") if the second argument, (arg[1]) is either not a positive integer (args[1]>0) or if its not even of an integer type normally. I can test if its not a positive integer, but I could do with a hand on how to compare whether the contents of a string array is or isn't parsable to an integer?

```
public class Repeat {

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(parseAndRep(args));
}
public static String parseAndRep(String[] args){ 
    if (args.length<2){
        return"Error: insufficient arguments";
    }
    if (Integer.parseInt(args[1]<1) || **//TODO Work out if correct type**) {
        return "Error: second argument not a valid positive integer";
    }

    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    String repeatstring = args[0];
    while (n!=1){
        repeatstring = repeatstring +" "+ args[0];
        n= n-1;
    }
    return repeatstring;
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc for `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: Also, the `args` parameter of the conventional `main()` method will always be of type `String[]` and therefore its elements will be of type `String`. Whether this `String` is parse-able into any other types is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `args` parameter of the `main()` method is always of type `String[]`. What you want to do is *not* to check the type (that has another meaning entirely), but you want to see if the `String` instance you have *is parseable* into an integer. To do that you can always check to see that the string matches a regular expression that only accepts digits:

```
if(!args[1].matches("\\d+"); {
   return "Error: second argument is not a valid positive integer";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String args1 = "12345678";
        boolean isNumber = args1.matches ("-?\\d+");
        if(!isNumber){
            // throw exception
        }
        //do parsing
        System.out.println(isNumber);
```

Above expression validate the numeric values , in case you need to extend to support decimals  you may use 
`-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?`

Answer (score 0):

You probably get a compile error on the following statement, at the indicated position:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(args[1]<1) || **//TODO Work out if correct type**) {
                            ^
```

This is because `args[1]` is a string and you cannot compare a string with `<`. What you probably want to do is

```
if (Integer.parseInt(args[1])<1 || **//TODO Work out if correct type**) {
```

This statement while parse `args[1]` to an int *before* comparing it with the value `1`. The problem is that this will throw a NumberFormatException if the number is not an interger.

You can check if a string is numeric with the StringUtils.isNumeric from the [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library, which has a very good and efficient implementation.